# Laravel: Foreach loop showing same data multiple time in blade

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have created `packages` table now I am trying to fetch multiple package column data in home page but every package showing in multiple time.

`package_detcontents` table have 3 column by id `PKID` i want to fetch this 3 column table by `packages` `PKID` into 1 field but `package_detcontents` table have 3 column that why its show 3 time

Here is my code

```
    @foreach($package as $pkg) 
    <a href="/{{ $city->CityName }}/packages/{{ $pkg->enventNm }}/{{$pkg->PKID}}/{{$pkg->EvnId}}/{{$pkg->link}}">

        <div class="wrapper_data list_data">
         <div class="item_data">
           <div class="package_images_data">
            <img src="/images/admin/event/packages/{{$pkg->link}}/thumbnail/{{$pkg->images}}" />
             </div>
             <div class="details_data"><div class="_1uv9Cbddd"> {{$pkg->PkgNm}}</div>

              <div class="_1uv9Cb">
               <div class="_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK">₹{{ number_format($pkg->price) }}</div>
                 <div class="_3auQ3N _2GcJzG">₹ {{ number_format($pkg->cross_price) }}</div>
                   <div class="VGWI6T"><span>{{$pkg->off_percent}}% OFF</span></div><br>
                     <div class="_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;{{$pkg->forpeople}}</div>
                   </div>
                   <p><h6>{{$pkg->nature}}<br></h6> {{$pkg->ContentList}}<br></p>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
      </a>
  @endforeach
```

I am fetching data from 2 table by id `PKID`

table one: `packages`

```
PKID  PkgNm  price  cross_price  images     forpeople

1      name   200      300       hdhdh.jpg    5
```

table two: `package_detcontents`

```
  PkdetCntId   PKID  BsNaId   ContentList 

   1             1    2       "dhjdjhd, djhdh, hjdd"
   2             1    3       "hdhj, hdhjd, dhhd"
   3             1    4       "hjdhj, dhjhj, dhj"
```

I am trying to fetch this package one time by id `PKID` but it's showing 3 time.

Here is my controller

```
 $package = DB::table("packages as pkg")
    ->select(DB::raw("pkg.PKID, pkg.EvnId, pkg.PkgNm, pkg.link, pkg.cross_price, pkg.off_percent, pkg.images, pkg.price, pkg.forpeople, pkg.Minsrating, pkg.Plsrating, pkg.remark, pkg.Status, pcn.ContentList, pcn.nature, ev.enventNm"))

    ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT pd.PKID, pd.BsNaId, pd.ContentList, bn.nature FROM package_detcontents AS pd INNER JOIN busi_natures AS bn ON pd.BsNaId = bn.BsNaId Group By pd.PKID, pd.BsNaId, pd.ContentList, bn.nature) as pcn"), function($join){
        $join->on("pcn.PKID","=","pkg.PKID");
    })
    ->leftJoin("events as ev","ev.EvnId","=","pkg.EvnId")
    ->where("pkg.Status", "=", "Active")
    ->where("ev.enventNm", "=", $envent)
    ->orderBy("pkg.PKID")
    ->paginate(50);
```

Comment: where are the rest of the table and its structures

Comment: As your query contains a left join which links related packages, of which there are three, the result from the database will be 3 rows which you're iterating over, hence the repetition.

Do you have any models set up in your Laravel app, as you can define the relationship there (https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships)?

Comment: please explain your question???? this information is not enough and  you are writing complex query which is confusing

Comment: @SherazKhan I have update the question please check

Comment: @JuliusFasema I have update the question please check

Comment: if you need one time then why you are using joins cause all the 3 records in package_detcontents table are different